# How to set Uart Baudrate to 345600 for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: uart, ftdi

I would like to set the Baudrate of my ttyUSB0 device to 345600 Baud. but looks like its not a standard baud rate (230400 or 460800 is supported). Is there any way to set the baud rate to 345600 in the linux shell?

I did it with my c program but there I loose packages and would like to try it with minicom or any standard shell program.

thanks for your help!

Comment: I assume you have already tried `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 345600` then?

Comment: yes that's not working: stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 345600
stty: invalid argument „345600“

Comment: `picocom`, for example, may be build with _BOTHER_ support (needs also support from the driver).